# How do i not show alternative routes through google map

Tags: google-maps, directions

I have tried like this but still i am not getting..
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=28.7041,77.1025&destination=25.5941,85.1376&travelmode=driving&alternatives-parameter=false

I guess, I am missing some parameters

Comment: It should be `alternatives=false`

Comment: i had tried that too,but still not have luck!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control of alternate routes is only (currently) available in the Google Maps Javascript API v3 DirectionsService and in the Directions Web Service.

- [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/overview#optional-parameters)
- [DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests)